# How to edit files remotely on Windows system

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to edit files on a remote Windows system using VS Code.
I know this can be done on Unix systems with SSH-Remoting.
Is there a similar extension for VS Code to open a remote session on Windows systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed the instructions to configure SSH server on my remote system:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse

And then used VS Code:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_getting-started

I wasn't previously aware that this all works for Windows now too.

I have successfully setup a remote SSH session to another Windows system!